# How to use counter variable inside List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This question is about List Comprehension. However, the iterables are a bit complex so I am confused about how to write this List Comprehension.

So, I have Some pydantic class like this

```
class textbox(BaseModel):
    x1: int
    y1: int
    x2: int
    y2: int
    
class Page(BaseModel):
    color: List[RGB]
    textboxes: List[textbox]
    
class Notepad(BaseModel):
    pages: List[Page]
```

Assuming all of them have appropriate values assigned to them. I want to do a List Comprehension like this so that I can access each of the Page separately and for every Page access each of the textbox and put them inside one list.

```
TotalTextBox = [textbox in textboxes for Notepad.pages[i].textboxes]
```

But I am facing a problem because List Comprehension is not letting me use the counter variable **i**. Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thank you.

P.S. I don't want to use enumerate. I want a simple list as result.

Comment: There's a function that takes a list as a parameter and returns tuples of `(index, element)` for each element... can't remember its name.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK: You mean `enumerate()`.

Comment: Hi @Haroldo_OK , I have found something called enumerate, it is a builtin function of python. But it returns enumerate object as I understand. What I want is a simple List.

Comment: `[tb for page in notepad.pages for tb in page.textboxes]`…?

Comment: Perhaps you could first try a normal `for` loop to make sure you can get what you want. Lots of for loops can be converted to list comprehensions.

Comment: What's wrong with just iterating over the (list of) pages as well? You obviously know how to iterate over the (list of) textboxes – same thing.

Comment: An enumerated object can be used in a list comprehension, and in fact, in most places you would use a list; no problems there.

Comment: Yes, while `enumerate()` returns an object, it is designed to be iterated over. There are loads of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops/522578#522578) on this website.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide and update your question with example data to help users reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would wish to use `enumerate` function in Python.

I would advise to start simple, and use multiple for loops as you know how to implement this.

Then slowly move this into a comprehensive list. It is often easier to break down your problem into stages and transition this into your desired answer.

An example of how `enumerate` works with list comprehension to apply this to your problem.

```
a_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
enumerate_list = [(index, element) for index, element in enumerate(a_list)]
```

Printing the list would look like follows:

```
print(enumerate_list)
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

As per suggestion of Haroldo, to prove this does in fact provide your final result of a list, if you print the type like this:

```
print(type(enumerate_list))
```

The output will be like such:

```
<class 'list'>
```

This can be modified to suit your need, just apply the knowledge of your lists and take it slowly.

Comment: As per the question: "I *don't* want to use enumerate."

Comment: This question was seemingly edited whilst I posted this answer.

Comment: As far as a can see, the reason they don't want to use `enumerate()` is because they don't understand how and why it would work. But work, it would: the end result would be a list; the intermediate type does not matter. Maybe you could add an extra line printing the type of `enumerate_list` showing that it is, in fact, a list; it's clear to me, but might not be for others.

Comment: I have made this change to hopefully point them in the right direction. As it would definitely provide them with what they are after.

Comment: I forgot to explain more clearly the syntax details: `enumerate(a_list)` does return an enumerated object, but the expression around it, `[(index, element) for index, element in some_enumerated_object]` returns an list. In fact, if you wanted to make the whole comprehension return an enumerated object instead of a list, you would replace the square brackets `[]` with parentheses `()`.